# Any Joomla & PHP podcasts from which I can learn?

Tags: recommended-practices

Are there any quality podcasts regarding Joomla or PHP and web development that you listen and would recommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). Feel free to contribute in a constructive manner.

## Joomla Podcasts

#### **[Joomla Beat Podcast](http://joomlabe.at/podcast/)** by Peter Bui

This is a general podcast about Joomla. Lots of interesting interviews, very informative, good sound quality and overall very dynamic and positive.

---

## PHP Podcasts

#### **[PHP Town Hall](http://phptownhall.com/)** by Ben Edmunds, Phil Sturgeon

PHP Town Hall is a podcast / vlog related to php development and regularly has guests with experienced php developers who are implementing php solutions every day.

#### [Voices of the ElePHPant](http://voicesoftheelephpant.com/) by Cal Evans and E.I.C.C., Inc.

Interviews with different community members from different projects.

---

## Joomla Conferences

#### [J and Beyond](http://www.youtube.com/user/jandbeyondev/videos) by J and Beyond e.V.

Recordings from the J and Beyond e.V. (Germany)

---

## Web development

-- TO BE ADDED --